# jest check module function calls count

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I am pretty new to javascript and jest too and I have this use case in my tests

```
    jest.mock('./db' , ()=>{
    saveProduct: (product)=>{
    //someLogic
    return
    },
    updateProduct: (product)=>{
    //someLogic
    return
    }
})
```

This works fine and I can run my tests against it, but I still want to assert in my test cases that **updateProduct** is called 3 times, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Use Jest spies wherever you need to assert or mock functions.

Comment: but I think spy will call the real method implementation which I don't want to happen, moreover, the db is not accessible in my local env

Comment: So-called Jest spies are uniform stubs/spies/function mocks. There can be no implementation to use when you define it as `jest.fn()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how can you test these mock fn

```
const saveProductMock = jest.fn((product)=>{
    //someLogic
    return
});

const updateProductMock = jest.fn((product)=>{
    //someLogic
    return
})

 jest.mock('./db' , ()=>{
    saveProduct: saveProductMock,
    updateProduct: updateProductMock
})
```

```
expect(saveProductMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(saveProductMock.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(product)
```

Comment: what does this expression "saveProductMock.mock.calls[0][0]"  mean? for the first call for the first parameters to be product?

Comment: first [0] - first call of function, second [0] - argument index

Comment: I got the error : ReferenceError: Cannot access 'saveProductMock' before initialization at this line saveProduct: saveProductMock,

Answer (score 0):

You run mock on an exported module, then everywhere you import the module, it becomes mocked.

```
import db from './db'; // import db

jest.mock('./db', () => ({ // I think you want to return an object
  saveProduct: (product) => {
    //someLogic
    return
  },
  updateProduct: (product) => {
    //someLogic
    return
  }
}));


// assert
expect(db.updatePorduct).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
```